# Azure API management cache size

Tags: azure-api-management

Azure API management has different size caches depending on the pricing tier, and has the ability to add an external Redis cache to extend the default cache size.  Is there a good way to determine when the cache size would benefit from being increased?  For example, is there a way to see how much data is being cached at any one time, or how often calls are hitting or missing the cache?  The only thing I've found so far is indirect, by measuring the average response time and average service response time under the Analytics->Operations.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: The Analytics->Timeline->Cache graph will show overall cache hits and cache misses.

You can also go to Analytics->Requests and see the individual calls and whether or not and individual call hit or missed the cache.  

I still haven't found a way to see how much data is in the cache, or determining when there would be benefits to increasing the cache size.